# Words or phrases related to obvious hidden agendas

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm strugging to describe the concept of when someone is indirectly trying to influence another person to do or say something, but in quite a blatant or cliched way. One particular example is when someone theatrically winces or groans in order for another person to ask if they're alright/ask what's wrong.

Comment: They're being a drama queen.

Comment: Thank you, but it was more a word/phrase for the act of indirectly influencing sometime in a blatant or obvious manner rather than an adjective for exaggerated attention-seeking.

Comment: I can't see how they can be 'blatant' and indirectly influence something unless they show excessive emotion. A noisy rebuke or cry for help say is not indirect.